# make page peel effect better

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like your suggestions here for the following points

1. Make peel effect more realistic if possible.
2. Reduce the size of the peel (to be able to see the full Ad).

[Jsfiddle peel effect](https://jsfiddle.net/k3fqa2L8/5/)

I used a div *pagePeelsmallrotate* rotated at 24deg initially. Which i then animate its angle as well as dimensions .

Also div *pagePeelcontainer* dimensions are animated.

```
There are two functions
         var pagePeelopen = function() {}  /*opens the ad*/
         var pagePeelclose = function() {} /*closes the ad */
```

I tried skewing only the *pagePeelcontainer*  div and not its children to get small peel as provided here

```
css used to avoid child elements getting affected
#pagePeelcontainer > * {
    transform:skew(-45deg);
}
```

[image: skewed peel]

But couldn't get the peel effect properly on click of open.

[Jsfiddle skewed peel](https://jsfiddle.net/rbqjo24w/4/)

Let me know how i can do it

Comment: To Reduce the size of the peel (to be able to see the full Ad); change $('#pagePeelcontainer').stop().animate({
                width: desired,
                height: desired
            }

I don't quite understand your first point, make peel effect more realistic it is already, but you can change duration to get a slower or faster effect as required

Comment: @AhmadAlsanie Thank you. Can you provide me a fiddle link, where i can see peel size being reduced with the change you mentioned.

Comment: http://andrewplummer.github.io/Peel.js/ found this, but it would mean adding more to your site

Answer (score 0):

Changing this section of code

```
            $('#pagePeelcontainer').stop().animate({
                width: 1000,
                height: 1000
            }, {
                duration: 500
            });
```

Will reveal the whole advert, as for the peeling it looks pretty good the way it is

Comment: Thanks. but the peel effect changes if i increase it